# how to auto increment a dataframe column with time by specified time each and auto incrementing date with day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

have a df with values

```
             0     |   1
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  sun 
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  earth
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  mercury
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  moon
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  mars
2019-02-22 13:40:58|  jupyter
```

1.how to auto increment the time by one minute in each case

desired output 1.

```
            0      |   1
2019-02-22 13:41:58|  sun 
2019-02-22 13:42:58|  earth
2019-02-22 13:43:58|  mercury
2019-02-22 13:44:58|  moon
2019-02-22 13:45:58|  mars
2019-02-22 13:46:58|  jupyter
```

2.By using this we can add day in between

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')
```

resulting

```
2019-02-08 Fri 12:19:06
```

How to increment these also

output 2 (name of day included)

```
            0      |   1
2019-02-17 sun  13:41:58|  sun 
2019-02-18 mon  13:42:58|  earth
2019-02-19 tue  13:43:58|  mercury
2019-02-20 wed  13:44:58|  moon
2019-02-21 thur 13:45:58|  mars
2019-02-22 fri  13:46:58|  jupyter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert increment/ decrement `Series` or `array`s [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add or subtract `datetime`s:

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms')
```

If need for each unique datetimes increment and decrement minutes and days:

```
s1 = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(0).cumcount() + 1, unit='m')
s2 = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(0).cumcount(ascending=False), unit='d')
```

Or if all same datetimes in first column:

```
s1 = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(1, len(df) + 1), unit='m')
s2 = pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(len(df)-1,-1, -1), unit='d')
```

---

```
df[0] = (df[0] + s1 - s2).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
                         0        1
0  2019-02-17 Sun 13:41:58      sun
1  2019-02-18 Mon 13:42:58    earth
2  2019-02-19 Tue 13:43:58  mercury
3  2019-02-20 Wed 13:44:58     moon
4  2019-02-21 Thu 13:45:58     mars
5  2019-02-22 Fri 13:46:58  jupyter
```

Comment: gettin this non convertible value 2019-02-05 Tue 23:50:30 with the unit 'ms'

Comment: @hukkemaaru - then use `df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], format='%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: if i need only minutes to increase not date ?

Comment: @hukkemaaru - then remove `s2` from `df[0] + s1 - s2` to `df[0] + s1`